# Can I use anime.js in EJS files with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation, ejs, anime.js

Every time I try to pass the animation variable to the EJS file in `app.js` I am met with the following error:

```
ReferenceError: NodeList is not defined

at toArray (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\animejs\lib\anime.js:320:20)
at parseTargets (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\animejs\lib\anime.js:643:87)
at getAnimatables (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\animejs\lib\anime.js:648:16)
at createNewInstance (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\animejs\lib\anime.js:844:21)
at anime (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\animejs\lib\anime.js:932:18)
at C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\app.js:14:30
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\18317\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I'm using `<script src="anime.min.js"></script>` in my header.ejs (partial) and the following:

```
const anime = require('animejs');

var animation = anime({ targets: 'p', translateX: 250, rotate:
'1turn', backgroundColor: '#20c997', duration: 8000, loop: true });

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs"); app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {   res.render("home", {utils:
animation}); });
```